# Jaxb Marshaller.Generate output.xml file containing the same data of the input.xml file with an additional tag indicating the record process result

Tags: jaxb

I'm reading an xml file (Input.xml) using Unmarshall Jaxb using a my Pojo Object.

Reading Input File example with Unmarshaller.

```
    File file = new File(".\\src\\test\\files\\Input.xml");
    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(MerchantPayments.class);
    Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
    MerchantPayments MpObj = (MerchantPayments) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);
    // Process MpObj..
```

What i need to do now, is to generate an Output.xml file containing the same data of the Input.xml file, but adding a new tag called `<result>` indicating if the record has been succesfully loaded.

Which is the best way to generate the output.xml file using Jaxb Marshal functionality containing the same data of the input.xml and adding a new tag?

I need to generate a new Pojo of the output.xml file in order to add the new tag or there are others way using Jaxb Marshaller?

Below the Input.xml file and the output.xml file that I need to geneate with the additional tag `<result>`

Input.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
    <payments>
        <payment>
            <account>123</account>
            <order>110000000001</order>
            <amount>19.0</amount>
        </payment>
        <payment>
            <account>1234</account>
            <order>110000000002</order>
            <amount>20.0</amount>
        </payment>
    </payments>
```

Output.xml, containing the new tag `<result>` :

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
    <payments>
        <payment>
            <account>123</account>
            <order>110000000001</order>
            <amount>19.0</amount>
            **<result>Record loaded correctly</result>**
        </payment>
        <payment>
            <account>1234</account>
            <order>110000000002</order>
            <amount>20.0</amount>
            **<result>Record Failed</result>**
        </payment>
    </payments>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To add new tag in Output.xml, first, you have to add following property corresponding setter/getter method in MerchantPayments class.

```
@XmlElement(name = "result")
private String result;
```

After unmarshalling, you'll get **MpObj** where you have to set *"Record Failed"* text to result field. Now, you can marshalling MpObj and will get desired output in Output.xml.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. but in this way also the xsd file have to be modified in order to define the new element result and I cannot modify the original xsd file.